# Is it possible to set up a squid proxy server for a mobile hotspot device?

Tags: squid

I am going to buy a verizon "jet pack" mobile hotspot device (similar to  mifi) for my trailer, and want to minimize my bandwidth use while on the road. I'd like to somehow set up a small linux machine with a beefy SSD, running a squid proxy server (http://www.squid-cache.org/) with a video caching layer (https://cachevideos.com/).

Is this even possible? I'm not a home networking guru but my knowledge of general networking is decent. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here would appear to be "sort of".  The jet pack device - from what I could see in Google, but I did not spend to much time looking - appears to be a fairly simple device, so it is highly unlikely it could intercept packets and redirect them to your proxy (ie I doubt it can do transparent proxying).

That said, provided the Linux machine is on the same LAN as the other devices you may be manually configure proxies in the other devices to use the SQUID proxy - regardless of the mobile hotspot.

Of-course, there is another option - get a USB Cellular device and configure the box which you had earmarked to run squid to run as a router + proxy - this will allow you to do transparent proxying (of HTTP requests, and HTTPS requests if the devices accept the certificate generated by the transparent proxy).  I note that this is a fairly complex procedure to set up - both the transparent proxying and setting up the USB cellular device connection take a fair bit of knowledge (and you will also need DHCP + routing knowledge, but that is relatively straight forward)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Some follow-up questions: Would this qualify as that USB device? https://www.verizonwireless.com/internet-devices/verizon-global-modem-usb730l/#?sku=2540056. I haven't actually purchased the linux box for this yet... what kind of specs and accessories will it need to broadcast the wifi network and run the proxy? my budget is pretty flexible—I don't want it to be the bottleneck for traffic. In terms of complexity of setup, that's not really an issue. i'm a software dev and while i'm no expert I am confident i could tackle it and enlist some help from friends/coworkers.

Comment: I confess to not knowing this hardware - from the scant information online it looks like it could be an excellent solution - and a lot easier then the older dongles which require fiddling arround with serial devices and ppp settings - but I'm making some guesses about how it works.Fworks.For the cost, I'd certainly be giving it a go.

Comment: I can't be sure on specs for the system - but I'd imagine the most important part is to use an SSD, and have adequate RAM.  If you are going to use the box as the AP you need to ensure the wifi card is high quality and supported by hostap, but if power and space is not an issue I'd make sure the onboard Ethernet is supported and not realtek and connect it to a regular wifi router - this will probably give more reliable coverage and remove the need to run a dhcp server.